# how to check if the key array has the same value or more than one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have an array (variable $items) where there is the same invenid (more than one) how to check if there is more than one invenid and how to add a total_price from each existing array and create a new key that is discount_price.
this is my array :
[image: array]
![array][1]

```
function apply_promotion($items){   
        foreach($items as $key => $val){
            if(isset($val['promo'])){
                $promo_type = $val['promo']['slug'];
                $start_date = $val['promo']['startdate'];
                $end_date = $val['promo']['enddate'];
                if(($start_date != '0000-00-00') && ($end_date != '0000-00-00') && (strtotime(timetodate(DT_TIME, 3)) >= strtotime($start_date)) && (strtotime(timetodate(DT_TIME, 3)) <= strtotime($end_date))){
                    switch($promo_type){
                        case "item-promotion":
                            $purchase = dround($val['total_price'], 2, 1);
                            if($purchase >= $val['promo']['min_purchase'] && empty($val['promo_code'])){
                                $items[$key]['discount_price']= dround($val['promo']['discount_amount'], 2, 1);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        echo '<pre>'.print_r($items, 1).'</pre>';die();
        return $items;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add an example array of then output that you expect.

Comment: What does the given code do? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` with pass by reference

```
 foreach($a as $key => &$val){
   ($val['invenid'] > 1) ? ($val['total_price'] = 12.00) : '';
 }
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/Tu0cP)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_keys()`

Ex:

```
$array1 = array([0],[1]);

print_r(array_keys($array1));
```

it will return all keys in an array

more information you can find [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)